# Inserting several records at once - sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I have recently created a disk catalog program for myself, it is working fine.  The problem is, when i try to index my 2 TB HDD, the time taken to write 66K rows into sql table is taking a lot of time nearing 30min.

I am using sql client (sdf is the file extension).

Also, i am using two threads to insert data simultaneous saving 50% of time.

I am using vb generated table adapters only.

Your guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that adding threads is the answer because the processor has to do the same amount of work.  Take a look at using a bulk insert: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: Yes, that is correct and I agree with it, but I am not using a server, I am using sql compact.

Comment: Take a look at using this.  I will keep searching for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceresultset%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y342

Comment: That is a great information, but it does not support the new operating systems like win7.  thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at my SqlCeBulkCopy sample/library: http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks, but I cant still understand it.  I am new to coding. sorry.